# Applying RSI function to a list of Dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, finance

I have created a list of data frames of the closing prices of all of the S&P 500 companies. I would like to calculate RSI for each company.

```
library(BatchGetSymbols)

first.date <- Sys.Date()-365
last.date <- Sys.Date()

df.SP500 <- GetSP500Stocks()
tickers <- df.SP500$tickers

l.out <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers,
                         first.date = first.date,
                         last.date = last.date)

l.out$df.tickers$price.open <- NULL
l.out$df.tickers$price.high  <- NULL
l.out$df.tickers$price.low <- NULL
l.out$df.tickers$volume <- NULL
l.out$df.tickers$price.adjusted <- NULL
l.out$df.tickers$ret.adjusted.prices <- NULL
l.out$df.tickers$ret.closing.prices <- NULL


SP <- l.out$df.tickers

mylist <- split(SP, SP$ticker)
```

I tried using lapply but failed:

```
rsi <- lapply(names(mylist$price.close), RSI)
```

It produces a list of 0. I appreciate any help I can get on this! Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Also produces a "list of 0."

Answer (score 1):

Use `lapply` with an anonymous function to call the `RSI` function with the price.close. By default the first 14 values of the rsi will be NA because it calculates the 14 day rsi.

```
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(TTR)

# your code ...
rsi <- lapply(mylist, function(x) RSI(x$price.close))

head(rsi$ABT, 20)
 [1]       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA 63.69235
[16] 66.10698 69.69120 70.76959 72.24900 69.41154
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. However I got this output when I ran your code:  Error in naCheck(x, n) : Series contains non-leading NAs

Answer (score 0):

Consider `by` which compactly replaces `split` and `lapply` for grouping operations by factor(s) such as *ticker*. With one factor, output is a named list of whatever the function returns equal to the unique number of factor:

```
RSI_list <- by(SP, SP$ticker, function(sub) TTR::RSI(sub$price.close))
```

In case one of the tickers does not maintain valid close price, wrap call in `tryCatch` and return NAs for those problem cases:

```
RSI_list <- by(SP, SP$ticker, function(sub) 
                    tryCatch(TTR::RSI(sub$price.close),
                             error = function(e) return(NA)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. However I got the same output when I ran phiver's code: Error in naCheck(x, n) : Series contains non-leading NAs.

Comment: See edit wrapping call in `tryCatch` for any tickers with problematic prices.